# I installed mate and it destroyed unity & gnome ubuntu 16.04 - no network cant login

Tags: boot, grub2, unity, gnome, mate

I installed mate desktop and something went wrong.    I uninstalled it then and it also removed unity & gnome.    now i can't log in normal mode or recovery...my keyboard doesnt work (despite working fine in BIOS & GRUB ).    I cant use Ctrl Alt F1 etc to drop to TTY shell.
If I drop to command prompt in recovery mode I cant re-install ubuntu-desktop because my wifi doesnt work (USB wifi).  can't find device via lsusb or lshw

Is there anyway i can fix this from my other ubuntu OS install?   Or LIVE USB ?

Comment: Is your other Ubuntu OS install on the same computer?

Comment: yes it is, on a separate SSD drive.     DATA drives are shared between both OS.  Both OS is 16.04 , but my new one was installed from the latest updates & the old one was installed 3 or 4 years ago

Comment: If you can still access your old install via grub it would be quicker to boot it rather than Live USB and inspect your failed installation that way instead.

Comment: "it" was  " tasksel install ubuntu-mate "  which is command ive never used before, I thought it was a mate thing.    I also uninstalled it with "taskel remove ubuntu-mate"  unity & gnome failed mid uninstall & rebooting got me to the login screen at ultra low resolution & no keyboard action.   old kernel  got wifi & keyboard working again,  restored ubuntu-desktop & installed gnome-shell for ubuntu.  
the term.log file had nothing in it! only gnome was at login most apps are gone, I ran tasksel remove command again by mistake & same thing hap. -> no wifi but i can log into gnome shell

Comment: think i will fresh install ubuntu, ive already spent more time trying to fix than an an install would take, i resisted doing this because i had just done this & had things running sweet as.  lol  thanks for your help <3